# Getting null when storing data in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm storing data to database one field somewhere dissappears.

This is my code:

```
    public function artStore(FacilityRequest $request)
{
    $art = new Facility;

    $art->category()->attach($request->input('categories_list'));

    if(Input::hasfile('image'))
    {
    $request->file('image')->move(public_path('images/art/'), $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName());

    $art->image = 'images/art/' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    $art = Facility::create($request->all());

}
```

The category attaches good, but the `$art` itself becomes null. Can someone tell me why ?

This is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'facility_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `category_facility_facility` (`category_facility_id`, `facility_id`) values (2, ))
```

This is what happens when I do dd($request);

```
  +query: ParameterBag {#289 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
  +server: ServerBag {#293 ▼
    #parameters: array:30 [▼
      "DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "C:\xampp\htdocs\uzdarbis\laravel\public"
      "REMOTE_ADDR" => "::1"
      "REMOTE_PORT" => "57855"
      "SERVER_SOFTWARE" => "PHP 5.6.12 Development Server"
      "SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
      "SERVER_NAME" => "localhost"
      "SERVER_PORT" => "8888"
      "REQUEST_URI" => "/create-art-work"
      "REQUEST_METHOD" => "POST"
      "SCRIPT_NAME" => "/index.php"
      "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => "C:\xampp\htdocs\uzdarbis\laravel\public\index.php"
      "PATH_INFO" => "/create-art-work"
      "PHP_SELF" => "/index.php/create-art-work"
      "HTTP_HOST" => "localhost:8888"
      "HTTP_CONNECTION" => "keep-alive"
      "HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH" => "13360"
      "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL" => "max-age=0"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
      "HTTP_ORIGIN" => "http://localhost:8888"
      "HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS" => "1"
      "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
      "HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE" => "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryF4qxwnPWgFSBZl7r"
      "HTTP_REFERER" => "http://localhost:8888/facilities/add-new"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip, deflate"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "lt,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4,pl;q=0.2"
      "HTTP_COOKIE" => "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlByRUloN3djVVgxWDZ2MmpEN0lZRWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSU5lNkZieWcrY01KTG05Q3M5YmswcHNSQ3A0N05DQ2loTXVWbmszdnZldEl4TytMVkdZMTRYYUIwQjAxdEwwdmRjWFZTMnZtMzkzZUtMZHhnUE5nZWc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjRjMDEzZTEzNzA0N2M1NWFhNmVlMTQ5Mjc5YmI0MjIzODc0NTRhZGJmZDkyNjJlMTk4ZTM0ZjEwMDc1YTRkMzEifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlNPb3I3OHZqejVHOGg3V0FjWm9naGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSXkrcVhVRnJmXC9EVEVJOUJwR0hhYzZDVkZxcXh1V3NVUDM4RkdiNmQrZThwV0VPeklIZWxwSmNyeHp1NThBbm1rOXNLY0Q1S29xVDJNMmo4XC9RalBlQT09IiwibWFjIjoiMjNhMjE4NmUyMTUwZWE5YTJkYjhlMzU0ZWI3ODNhOTVmNzdiZTc1NWEwYjE5NzYzNDg0NzQ5N2U0Yjk3Njg1NCJ9"
      "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1448714404.5915
      "REQUEST_TIME" => 1448714404
      "CONTENT_LENGTH" => "13360"
      "CONTENT_TYPE" => "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryF4qxwnPWgFSBZl7r"
    ]
  }
```

This is my form:

```
      <div class="formaIkelimo" style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto"> 
    {!! Form::open(['url' => '/create-art-work/', 'files' => 'true']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('categories_list', 'Kategorija') !!}
            {!! Form::select('categories_list[]', $categories, null, ['id' => 'categories_list','class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">

    <label>Photo</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
  </div>    

    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Upload', ['class' => 'form-control btn btn-success']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}

    </div>
```

Comment: The error message says, there is no data you are sending for column `facility_id`.

Try this to check what data you are sending to database `dd($request->all())`

And I don't see any data you are sending for `facility_id` in your whole question. 

If your `dd($request->all())` return that you are sending data for `facility_id` Ex: `'facility_id'=>'someDataNotNull'` then make sure you mention `facility_id` is in your model to be mass assignment. Ex: `protected $fillable = ['category_facility_id','facility_id','someMoreIfNeede'];`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you're not sending an integer but something else. I think the database expects an integer.

could you use:

```
public function artStore(FacilityRequest $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

to see what the request contains?

Comment: could you open attributes, query and server by clicking on ▶ behind them and see what values they contain. Also add your form for more info.

Comment: in the form I only see ['id' => 'categories_list','class' => 'form-control'], assuming this sends the category_list id. But I don't see anyhting for the facility id, explaining why it is empty

Comment: Okay, now I understand. How would I add 'id' field to <img /> input ?

Comment: I don't think you could take that from the image itself, but from the filename would be a possibility if you used the facility id in the filename, but I don't recommend that. Why not add another select field, so the user selects the facility (just like you did with categorie list)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to attach a category to nothing. This is causing the error:

```
$art = new Facility;
$art->category()->attach($request->input('categories_list'));
```

Art is an instance of Facility. It's not entered into the database yet so it does not have an `id`. When you try to attach the category, then the `facility_id` is null. That is causing your error. The best way to handle this is by attaching it at the end - after you created the facility:

```
public function artStore(FacilityRequest $request)
{
    $art = new Facility;

    if(Input::hasfile('image'))
    {
         $request->file('image')->move(public_path('images/art/'), $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName());

         $art->image = 'images/art/' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    $art = Facility::create($request->all());

    $art->category()->attach($request->input('categories_list'));
}
```

This is assuming your request inputs are correct. Next time, you should `dd($request->all())` rather than `$request`.

Edit: I also realized that your `image` attribute won't be saved correctly with your current method. I suggest doing this, which is a bit cleaner too:

```
public function artStore(FacilityRequest $request)
{
    if(Input::hasFile('image'))
    {
         $request->file('image')->move(public_path('images/art/'), $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName());

         $request->merge(['image' => 'images/art/' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName()]);
    }

    $art = Facility::create($request->all());

    $art->category()->attach($request->input('categories_list'));
}
```

After the file has been moved to the designated area, the [`merge`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge) method basically overwrites `image` attribute with a new value. That way, you can just create the Facility object at the very end in one line. Then, you attach the category.

Comment: I get an error then. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Comment: What's your table structure like? What SQL query is it generating? Give us a bit more info. :)